# discord.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I've recently been coding my bot and all of a sudden I got the error (referring to title)

Code:

```
const { MessageEmbed, MessageReaction } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {name: 'poll',description: 'just a poll command',async execute(args, message, discord, client){const POLL = new MessageEmbed().setTitle('Initiate Poll?').setDescription('-poll to initiate a poll.').setColor('0xFFC300');

    if(!args[1]){
        message.channel.send({embeds: [MessageEmbed]});
    }

    let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(' ');

    message.channel.send(msgArgs).then(messageReaction => {
        messageReaction.react('');
        messageReaction.react('');
    });
}

}
```

message.channel.send works for every other command. So I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I tried using the command, was expecting an embed to show up, but instead, it crashed and gave me the error (title)

Comment: As you can tell by the error, `message.channel` seems undefined, can you show your **execute()** function of any one of the other commands which seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that you're forgetting to add `new` before the discord embed. The error is by your `args[1]` check.

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageReaction } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: 'poll',
  description: 'just a poll command',
  async execute(args, message, discord, client){
    const POLL = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Initiate Poll?')
    .setDescription('-poll to initiate a poll.')
    .setColor('0xFFC300');

    if(!args[1]){
      message.channel.send({embeds: [ new MessageEmbed().setDescription(`your text here`) ]});
    }

    let msgArgs = args.slice(1).join(' ');

    message.channel.send(msgArgs).then(messageReaction => {
        messageReaction.react('');
        messageReaction.react('');
    });
  }
}
```